# How to retrieve bytes sent received through SNMP

Tags: perl, snmp, oid

I am writing a Perl script that is supposed to retrieve bytes sent/received from a remote host, long story short I want to monitor network traffic. Notice that the host may be an actual host or something else like a router/switch etc. The data I retrieve is going to be stored on a Round Robin Database but that's not important.

First thing I do is to retrieve host's interfaces and then I am supposed to look for traffic usage. Can I do that using OID? Is there a table that stores those value?

```
use Net::SNMP;
use Net::SNMP::Interfaces;

main:
{

my $session;
my $hostname = '192.168.x.x';
my $community = 'test';
my $error;
my $oid = '';
my $result;

# RETRIEVING INTERFACES
my $interfaces = Net::SNMP::Interfaces->new(Hostname => $hostname, Community => $community);
my  @ifnames = $interfaces->all_interfaces();
foreach $interface (@ifnames) {
    my $name = $interface->name();
    print "$name\n";    
}

# SNMP SESSION OPEN
($session, $error) = Net::SNMP->session(-hostname => $hostname, -community => $community);
print "SESSION: $session\n";
if (!defined $session) {
    print "SESSION ERROR: $error\n";
    $session->close();
    exit(1);
}

# SNMP GET_REQUEST  
$result = $session->get_request(-varbindlist => [ $oid ]);
if (!defined $result) {
    $error = $session->error();
    print "GET_REQUEST ERROR: $error\n";
    $session->close();
    exit(1);
}

$result = $result->{$oid};
print "GET_REQUEST: $result\n";

# SNMP SESSION CLOSE
$session->close();
exit(0);

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ifHCOutOctets OID **1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.10** - outgoing traffic (bytes)

ifHCInOctets OID **1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.6** - incoming traffic (bytes)

So, if you need get statistic for port 1, then OID is:
1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.10.*1*

Comment: I get the following error: _Received noSuchName(2) error-status at error-index 1_ Looks like my MIB does not store those values.

Comment: What operating system do you use? Try to install net-snmp package, it contains some command-line unitilies for work with SNMP.
try to execute the following:
`snmpwalk -v2c -c test 192.168.x.x 1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.10`


BTW, is 'test' community existed on the remote host?

Comment: In the end I decided to monitor the interface instead of single ports. I used those OIDS: 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.INTERFACENUMBER 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.16.INTERFACENUMBER, the first one gives InOctets and second one gives OutOctets, many thanks btw!